# How to "Pick" row based on comparison of value in columns for every ID that is duplicated?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like this (many more columns):

```
cid        pid      type
C12         1         E
C34         1         F
C01         1         G
            2         F
            2         G
```

I want to 'pick' the max 'cid' and hide the row with the lesser value in the table when:

```
 1. 'cid' is present
 2. 'pid' is the same
```

If no 'cid' then I dont have anything to 'pick' the max row. 'cid' always begins with 'c', not sure if this causing me to fail since I am trying to pick the max of alphanumeric.

The new table should look like this:

```
cid        pid      type
C34         1         F
            2         F
            2         G
```

I have tried doing:

```
select max(cid) as cid from table.
```

but it's not working.

Also tried `group by`, but I have 50 columns and it's still not working:

```
select max(cid) as cid, pid,type
from table
group by cid, pid, type
```

When I try to group by just 'pid', I get an error, that I need to eventually group all columns.

---edit----

I am open to removing the join in the table that is creating the 'cid' in the final table out and doing a separate join if that helps. Ideally I would like to be able to 'pick' the row I want from the existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.cid is null
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where pid = t.pid and cid > t.cid
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/upY4S91eKi6QhfWwQ3DAQY/1).
Results:

```
| cid | pid | type |
| --- | --- | ---- |
| C34 | 1   | F    |
|     | 2   | F    |
|     | 2   | G    |
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=51349d2bc6dcffd3ad2f90a78e1818aa)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (pid)
        *
    FROM
        mytable
    WHERE cid IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY pid, cid DESC
) s

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE cid IS NULL
```

I split up the query into: `cid` exists and `cid` does not exist:

1. Do get the max of a certain group you can use the `DISTINCT ON` clause, which always gives the first record of an ordered group. In your case the group is `pid` and this is ordered by `cid` in `DESC`ending order to get the highest to the top. This record is the result.
2. After calculating these records simply `UNION` the records without any `cid` value.

Answer (score 0):

With window functions:

```
select cid, pid, kind
from (
         select cid, pid, kind, row_number() over (partition by pid order by cid desc nulls last ) as rn
         from demo
     ) as T
where cid is null or rn = 1;
```

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kPjgji1w2hm51JaBFGQzCL/0